# Record n- fixed size videos to sd card android

Tags: android, video, camera, android-camera, android-mediarecorder

I want to record **n-videos** of a fixed time duration and save all to sd card without terminating video As i need to upload them to server one by one. I have used this sample for create my own camera using FrameLayout [sample i used](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/107270/Recording-and-Playing-Video-on-Android). I have tried MediaRecorder for that purpose but unable to do more than 1.

I have tried **recorder.setMaxDuration(FIXED_TIME_IN_MILLIS);** but unable to start it again and as per docs there is no guarantee that the recorder will have stopped by the time.

**Please suggest me what should i do for this, if any similar sample it'll help me a lot**

Comment: You can get significantly more control over the recording process if you feed the preview frames to `MediaCodec`, but there are some limitations.  Are you recording audio as well as video?  What API level are you targeting?

Comment: No i want to record video only, and just now i am not considering API level as looking for soln now. Using SurfaceView with camera or MediaRecorder is not suitable for this situation..? I am not aware much with MediaCodec

Comment: There are some recording examples in Grafika (https://github.com/google/grafika); see "Show + capture camera" and "Constant capture" for examples.